# Content security policy is blocking React Google Charts how to get past it

Tags: google-chrome-extension

My current content security policy section of code allows inline. The app blocks rendering of the charts during the production build. How should I add permissions for google charts I can't find anything regarding this on their page:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-charts#installation

My current code (manifest.json):

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'sha256-/8hmd4DqwVs419dLsNQ5IDmaKuXZyjZnNQcgWS+mCk4='; object-src 'self'",
```

Answer (score -1):

Needed to add:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

to the header to make it work